# Assign multiple DB field entries to a single variable

Tags: php

I have a PHP question, which I was hoping someone might be able to answer quite easily…
Basically the code exports database fields into an excel file, but I need two database fields to be added to a single excel field:

Normal working single db field:

```
$worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['date_added'] );
```

Not working (in this case I would like both ‘shipping_firstname’ and ‘shipping_lastname’ to be added to a single excel cell):

```
$worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['shipping_firstname'] && $row['shipping_lastname'] );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['shipping_firstname'] . ' ' . $row['shipping_lastname'] );
```

In PHP you use the `.` operator to concatenate strings.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfectly. I am embarrassed by how much time I spent trying to solve this today, your response made me realise how far off I was and saved me a heap more time! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Concatenations are using a dot(`.`) on PHP

```
$worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['shipping_firstname'] . " " . $row['shipping_lastname'] );
```

`&&` is used to combined boolean value and is mostly used in conditional statement like `if`

Answer (score 0):

If you want two fields added to a single excel field, then can't you simply concatenate them?

```
$worksheet->writeString( $i, $j++, $row['shipping_firstname'] . ' ' . $row['shipping_lastname'] );
```